# how to mark a function paramter Type as Function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm learning typescript and I don't know how to mark a function paramter as function.
For example in this code I'm passing a setState function via props to children component.

```js
const SelectCity = ({ onShowCity }: Function): JSX.Element => {}
```

This `Function` type return an error `Property 'onShowCity' does not exist on type 'Function'`

I tried function(lowercase) as will and returned another error `Cannot find name 'function'. Did you mean 'Function'?`

this is my implomention. showCity is a variable with a false value;
i passed the setShowCity as a paramter so its a function and accepts boolean.

```js
  const [showCity, setShowCity] = useState(false);

          {showCity ? (
            <SelectCity onShowCity={setShowCity} />
          ) : (
            <SelectState onShowCity={setShowCity} />
          )}
```

How should I do this ?

and another question `JSX.Element` is the correct Type for functional component return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. The parameter is **not** a function. It is an object where the value of one of the properties is a function.
2. Function types are [well documented in the manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html) and need the arguments and return value defining.

So (and I'm guessing about the shape of your particular function here):

```
type MyProps = {
    onShowCity(foo: string, bar: number): void; 
};

const SelectCity = ({ onShowCity }: MyProps): JSX.Element => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. remember that you need to type all of the props (though you only have one now), i.e. the props' type is an object type, not a single function
2. be more specific about the function's type.

For instance, if the handler would accept a string argument and return nothing, i.e.

```
function handleShowCity(city: string) { 
  alert(`Nice, ${city} is beautiful this time of the year`);
}
```

you'd type the props as

```
function SelectCity({ onShowCity }: {onShowCity: (city: string) => void}) { ... }
```

(You don't need to necessarily explicitly specify the return type anyway.)

You can also separate the type into an interface so it can be e.g. exported:

```
interface SelectCityProps {
  onShowCity: (city: string) => void;
}

function SelectCity({ onShowCity }: SelectCityProps) { ... }
```